# How to calculate VAh for online UPS?

Tags: voltage, current, ups

I have the following parameters. Now I want to calculate the VAh for he online UPS.

**Input**: 
Input Voltage Range (Load < 50%):   118 ~ 295 V (± 5 V) 
Input Voltage range ((Load > 50%)): 160 ~ 295 V (± 5 V) 
Frequency:  40 ~ 70 Hz 
Power Factor    ≥ 0.99 @ full load

**Battery** 
DC Voltage  72 V (6* 7.0 Ah battery inside) 
Charge current  1.5 amps 
UPS Overload / UPS Short-Circuit    110% / 300%

**Output** 
Voltage Range   208 / 220 / 230 / 240 V AC 
Frequency Range (Synchronized Range)    47 ~ 53 Hz or 57 ~ 63 Hz

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: don't know how to do it pls help

Comment: Is this a homework question? Why are you trying to calculate the VAh? What VAh are you trying to calculate? The load or the battery?

Comment: both @Transistor

Comment: Sorry, if you don't answer all the questions I can't help. Read the comments carefully and try to answer each point.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, VAh is calculated for the battery. VAh is a battery parameter.

Here, overall battery pack voltage = 72 V (the entire battery pack, which, according to your question comprises six 12V batteries). Since the batteries are in series, remains the same = 7 Ah (Ah is similar to current (A) in series configuration).

Hence VAh = 72 x 7 = 504 VAh